# run models together

Tags: php, mysql, model, pdo, dao

Applying each individual model, there is no way to rollback or prevent any insert run
MODEL_A: MODEL_B inserts even if shoot `Exception`
MODEL_B: MODEL_A inserts even if shoot `Exception`

```
$ MODEL_A-> insert();
$ MODEL_B-> insert();
```

//MODEL.A

```
try {
    $statement = $pdo-> prepare( "INSERT INTO ..." );
    $statement-> execute();
}catch{}
```

//MODEL.B

```
try {
    $statement = $pdo-> prepare( "INSERT INTO ..." );
    $statement-> execute();
}catch{}
```

//procedual would be easy workaround

```
try {
    #beginTransaction;
    $statement = $pdo-> prepare( "INSERT INTO ..." );
    $statement-> execute();

    $statement = $pdo-> prepare( "INSERT INTO ..." );
    $statement-> execute();
    #commit;
}catch{}
```

If the first insert is inserted, and the second trigger an error, do not have as the first rollback
Both need to be tested before performing the action
Anyone have any suggestions of how to solve this problem?
Thanks

Comment: use a `START TRANSACTION` at the begin of your code, and `COMMIT` at the end is all is OK. If not, `ROLLBACK`. see : http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/commit.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to explicitly start a transaction by turning off autocommit and then either committing or rolling back the transactions after you have done your tests. You can do this with PDO using the [beginTransaction()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/pdo.begintransaction.php), [commit()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/pdo.commit.php), and [rollback()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/pdo.rollback.php) functions.

If the insert is in disparate classes, you can pass a reference to your `$pdo` object.

```
class ModelA {
    function insert(&$pdo){
        $statement = $pdo->prepare( "INSERT INTO ..." );
        $statement->execute();
    }
}

class ModelB {
    function insert(&$pdo){
        $statement = $pdo->prepare( "INSERT INTO ..." );
        $statement->execute();
    }
}
```

Your code would then look like the below:

```
// disable autocommit
$pdo->beginTransaction(); 

$modelA = new ModelA();
$modelA->insert($pdo);

$modelB = new ModelB();
$modelB->insert($pdo);

// check for errors, and either commit() or rollback()
$hasErrors = ? // Add your code to check for errors
if ($hasErrors){
    $pdo->rollback();
} else {
    $pdo->commit();
}
```

Comment: sorry, you would just need to pass a reference to `$pdo` to do that

Comment: would look like? `beginTransaction | $MODEL_A::insert() | $MODEL_B::insert() | commit`

Comment: See my update, you would either need to pass a reference to `$pdo` when you create the objects, or as a parameter to the `insert()` method since it looks like you are using static methods?

Comment: thanks for the update. Static method used to facilitate viewing. It would not be the responsibility of each model must decide whether to start beginTransaction? just want to make sure not to break the "rules"

Comment: Only if the changes within that model are atomic, otherwise they have to share a resource.

Comment: understood. Many thanks for the help, I'll choose the answer! you would know where I can find some references about this type of transaction?

Comment: Not off the top of my head, but think of it this way - on a single database connection you have to start a transaction, run your CRUD statements, and then decide to either commit or roll back. If you don't pass a single object around by reference, there is no way to guarantee that all of the aforementioned will happen on the same connection.